# Updating a PDF Barcode Field

Tags: pdf, adobe, barcode

I have an existing PDF template that I have to edit. I know pretty much nothing about messing with PDFs (fair warning). There is a standard barcode that the customer wants changed to a Data Matrix barcode.

What is in the PDF template right now:

[image: Current Barcode]

So far, I have the following:

1. Open the PDF template (opens in Adobe Acrobat Pro)
2. Go to Tools > Forms > Edit in Designer. This opens the PDF in LiveCycle Designer.
3. Right click on the on the barcode and go to Palettes > Object. This opens an object tab for the barcode.

Now, it looks like there is a drop down to edit the barcode type. But it's disabled, and I don't know why.

[image: Disabled Dropdown]

The option to right click on the barcode and select Change Object Type is also disabled.

Does anyone know how to edit the barcode type to be a Data Matrix?

*UPDATE* I do not want to have to re-create the barcode. I just want to edit what is there. Not add and remove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I managed to find a solution. At the top of LiveCycle, I originally had two tabs.

[image: Original Tabs]

If you right click on the gray space next to the tabs, you can choose "XML Source", which makes a new tab appear.

[image: New Tabs]

In the "Design View" tab, I clicked on the bar code I wanted to change (so that it was selected). I then clicked on the "XML Source" tab. It takes you directly to the bar code code, which looked like the following (note that I removed some attributes and tags and replaced them with ...)

```
<field ...>
    <ul>
        <barcode type="code128" ... />
    </ul>
    ...
</field>
```

That `type` attribute on the `barcode` tag just needed to be changed to `dataMatrix`, and the barcode was updated to the correct type.

Note: I also had to modify the heights of the fields, etc. But this is pretty self explanatory.